# Convert frame pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datareader

I receive the output from my pandas datareader as the following:

```
       Date        AAPL         ACN
0 2016-11-21  111.730003  119.680000
1 2016-11-22  111.800003  119.480003
2 2016-11-23  111.230003  119.820000
3 2016-11-25  111.790001  120.739998
4 2016-11-28  111.570000  120.760002
```

What I that the frame looks like:

```
       Date   Minor   Adj Close
0 2016-11-21  AAPL    111.730003  
1 2016-11-22  AAPL    111.800003  
2 2016-11-23  AAPL    111.230003  
3 2016-11-25  AAPL    111.790001  
4 2016-11-28  AAPL    111.570000  
0 2016-11-21  ACN     119.680000
1 2016-11-22  ACN     119.480003
2 2016-11-23  ACN     119.820000
3 2016-11-25  ACN     120.739998
4 2016-11-28  ACN     120.760002
```

How can I converte my code that I receive the output mentioned above? The code looks like:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

DataLevels = pdr.DataReader(['ACN','AAPL'], 'yahoo', '2016-11-19', '2016-12-1')
DataLevels = DataLevels['Adj Close'].reset_index()
DataLevels.rename(columns={'minor': ['ACN','AAPL'], 'Adj Close': 'Adj Close'}, inplace=True)
print(DataLevels)
```

Comment: @MaxU 
I receive the following error message:SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to reshape the `DF` from wide to long format:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'], value_name='Adj Close', var_name='Minor')
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is much better ;)

Comment: @MaxU, Thanks for that.

Comment: @MCM, you can simply replace `df` with your "DataLevels": `pd.melt(DataLevels['Adj Close'].reset_index(), id_vars='Date', value_name='Adj Close', var_name='Minor')`

Comment: @MCM, If you want to rename the column after melting, you could then do - `pd.melt(DataLevels['Adj Close'].reset_index(), id_vars=['Date'], value_name='Adj Close', var_name='Minor').rename(columns={'Minor': 'Ticker'})`. Since you haven't [accepted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) before, you may want to do that so that it indicates to the wider community that this solution has solved your problem successfully.

Comment: @NickilMaveli Thanks a lot. I just figured it faster out as I could delete my post :). I think the post can be closed.

Comment: @NickilMaveli oops somehow he did not took it. But now it should be accepted. Thanks again

Comment: @MCM, You're welcome. Whoa! You've finally learnt how to accept answers. And from now on, as a good practice while asking questions, always accept the best answer you feel has solved your question to your likingness/expectation :-)

Comment: @NickilMaveli, sorry for asking again. I was thinking I understood melt but somehow not. When trying to get all the data from yahoo (open, high, low, etc.) how would that work out here?

Comment: @MCM: Ideally, you should post that as a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Nevertheless, could you edit your post with the said data you're trying to obtain?

Comment: @NickilMaveli, you are write. I post an seperate post. Maybe you could have a look: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227023/try-to-include-an-column-based-input-and-file-name-in-pnadas-dataframe-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227023/try-to-include-an-column-based-input-and-file-name-in-pnadas-dataframe-in-python)

Comment: @NickilMaveli, sorry for bothering you again. How can I use melt when I use all the output given by yahoo finance and not just the adj_close?